# Query on Wait until API Event in Journey Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I am trying to use the Wait until event feature on journey builder. As per your recommendation, I am not using a primary key. I am trying to update the Data extension with another record with the same email ID and there's a boolean field I am using as filter criteria. I am not clear what would the feature do if there are two records in the DE, one with FALSE and another with TRUE at a later time. Would one record move into event occurred and another to no event?

Answer (score 0):

If the first record meets the criteria and enters the event occurred state, it will not be evaluated again, even if the second record with the same email ID meets the criteria at a later time. Only one record with the same email ID can enter the event occurred state and only the first record that meets the criteria will be evaluated.